# Entity Framework .Where method chaining

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there any difference between these two ways of querying the context?

```
Firm firm = base.context.Firms
            .Where(f => f.SomeId == someId)
            .Where(f => f.AnotherId == anotherId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

Firm firm = base.context.Firms
            .Where(f => f.SomeId == someId && f.AnotherId == anotherId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

It seems that chaining is perfectly fine to accomplish the AND condition.  I don't believe you can chain OR statements.  Is there a reason to prefer one over another, or scenarios when one is better/more efficient?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

They should both produce the same end result (if I'm not mistaken) but I find the the second is more readable and better shows the original intent.

---

**Update**

I just verified the above statement using LINQPad. Both queries will, in fact, product the same SQL.

For example:

```
context.SomeTable.Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
                 .Where(c => c.Name.Contains("F"))
                 .Select(c => c.Name);
```

Produces:

```
SELECT [t0].[Name] 
FROM [SomeTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] LIKE @p0) AND ([t0].[ParentId] IS NULL)
```

Which is the same SQL that is produced by:

```
context.SomeTable.Where(c => c.ParentId == null && c.Name.Contains("F"))
                 .Select(c => c.Name);
```

---

You could also compact things a little more (which I find preferable for the same reasons as above):

```
var firm = base.context.Firms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.SomeId == someId 
                                                  && f.AnotherId == anotherId);
```

Comment: The first one is most readable to me. You can immediately see there are two separate conditions which must match and they line up perfectly. Sure the second one also has two conditions but it takes the extra second to parse out that there is a && in the line.

Comment: +1 for LINQPad.  LINQPad: http://www.linqpad.net/.  It's a wonderful little tool for LINQ.

Comment: I have a question regarding your last syntax (FirstOrDefault(Predicate...)), given that ObjectQuery implements both IEnumerable and IQueryable, what is the compiler overload resolution algorithm for choosing IQueryable.FirstOrDefault() over IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() so that you see the predicate shows up in the generated SQL on Profiler or LINQPad? For more please take a look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047266/ef-wherex-x-columnval-1-vs-firstordefaultx-x-column-1/4047559#4047559 Thanks.

Comment: (Realizing this Q&A is now older than some second graders...) Strangely, in EF Core, I've got a query that only executes the last comparison if I `&&` in a single `Where()`, but if I put each clause in its own `.Where(l =>...)`, I'm golden. /preStandupFaceRubAndShrug ;^D

Comment: I hate the last "compact" example which shows this terrible formatting thingy

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that as long as you are working with in `IQueryable` (as your context collections probably are), using the chained extensions vs the full predicate clause achieves the same thing. This is because `IQueryable` allows for deferred execution so essentially the same SQL is being generated behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug through the code and see the SQL that gets generated as a result of each.  I would imagine it turns into the same query.